# Error extracting XML values in PostgreSQL using XPath: SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at or near "["

Tags: xml, postgresql, xpath

I'm trying to extract values from XML stored in the PostgreSQL DB using XPath. I've got an error:

> SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at or near "["

My SQL is:

```
-- Find "e" nodes which have "p1" child nodes and does not have "p3" child nodes
WITH tbl(p_xml) AS (
   SELECT '<root>
    <e id="1">
        <p1>P1</p1>
        <p2>P2</p2>
    </e>
    <e id="2">
        <p1>P1</p1>
        <p3>P2</p3>
    </e>
    <e id="3">
        <p2>P1</p2>
        <p3>P3</p3>
    </e>
</root>'::xml
)
select * 
FROM   tbl
where
    (xpath('count(/root/e/p1)', p_xml)[1]::text)::int > 0 and 
    (xpath('count(/root/e/p3)', p_xml)[1]::text)::int = 0
```

I've seen plenty of examples on StackOverflow with using squares to get data (as **xpath** function returns array), but all of them fails with the same error on my PostgreSQL. I tried this on PostgreSQL DB versions 9.6 and 10.1 with no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because your query lacks a brackets. Anyways, if you want to return just `e` elements that fulfill that condition you'll need to shred the XML, for example :

```
WITH tbl(p_xml) AS (
   SELECT '<root>
    <e id="1">
        <p1>P1</p1>
        <p2>P2</p2>
    </e>
    <e id="2">
        <p1>P1</p1>
        <p3>P2</p3>
    </e>
    <e id="3">
        <p2>P1</p2>
        <p3>P3</p3>
    </e>
</root>'::xml
)
SELECT e
FROM tbl
CROSS JOIN LATERAL UNNEST(xpath('//e[p1 and not(p3)]', p_xml)) e
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/FZGP41665

Comment: I knew, there must be a better approach :-)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not experienced with `postgresql`, but this seems to work:

```
where
    (xpath('count(/root/e/p1)', p_xml)::text[])[1]::int > 0 and 
    (xpath('count(/root/e/p3)', p_xml)::text[])[1]::int = 0
```

It looks, as if `xpath()` must be casted to an array of string, where you pick the first element to cast it to `int`. Not very intuitive.

There might be a better approach...